# Bootstrap form-horizontal with form-group and razor html helper button alignment issues

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, razor

I am having issues correctly aligning buttons within with my razor markup.

In a `form-horizontal`:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
      @html.labelfor
      @html.editorfor
      @html.validationmessagefor
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
     <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" id="buttonId">
         <span>Button Label</span>
     </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

The button aligns with the `<label>` element, and I am really looking for it to align with the `<input>`.  I have tried using margins and padding but it has not produced the results I am looking for.

**EDIT:** I have included a [Fiddle Link here](https://jsfiddle.net/jfakey/gL2g7swf/)

Comment: I don't sure what you have to align, but with bootstrap to align btn with other elements control if that elements have the same margin.

Comment: @Mark I haven't implemented any changes to the CSS files, so the bootstrap template is what is there.  I would like to move the button using `style=""`

Comment: @user3708225 check the posted answer and let me know if you requires any further assistance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elements with the `form-group` class act as rows, so I'd use a combination of that and `row` elements to make it happen:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <label class="control-label" for="whatItsFor">Label Text:</label>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <input class="form-control text-box single-line" ... />
...
```

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/pnkk7p4k/)**

Note that I've changed your breakpoints to `xs` for this demo.

If you're able to update to Bootstrap 3.2, you can use [**column offsets**](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-offsetting) instead of empty columns:

```
<div class="col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-2">
    <button id="buttonId" class="btn btn-default" ...>Texty</button>
</div>
```

**[Demo 2](https://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/pnkk7p4k/2/)**

Comment: Perfect!!  Thanks for the help.  I was trying to add styling to the button and it was shrinking it and moving everything else around it

Comment: Yeah, custom positioning should be an absolute last resort when using a library as comprehensive as Bootstrap.

Comment: ah yes.  I didn't even catch the empty div.  This is project is a little bit of a collaboration and I assumed that it was a placeholder, but in asking my teammate the response was: "I didn't know how to move the button."  Indeed.

Answer (score 0):

```html
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label" for="whatItsFor">Label Text:</label>
                    <input class="form-control text-box single-line input-sm" id="rwhatItsFor" maxlength="200" name="mvcModelBinding" readonly="true" type="text" value=""> <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="whatItsFor" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
    
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2"></div>
            <div class="col-md-4 form-group">
                <button id="buttonId" class="btn btn-default" type="button" value="valueHere"> <span>
                Texty
            </span>
    
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Some explanation of what you've changed or added would improve your answer.